# Executar audio em uma WebView Android

Tags: java, android, webview, áudio

Como faço para executar audio de uma url utilizando uma WebView neste caso uma URL de uma radio, segue o codigo abaixo.

```
WebView mWebView;
mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mWebView.loadUrl("http://minharadio.com.br");

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: se o audio está na pagina, acredito que se ele abre a url normalmente qual é a dificuldade que voce está tendo mais especificamente?

Comment: Isso deveria funcionar isso voçe tem razão, mas o audio não executa.

Comment: essa pagina funciona, vou fazer uns testes aqui, pode ser?
se voce postar a url correta posso ver melhor

Comment: Segue a url http://agenciaabound.com.br/radio/radio.php.

Comment: Ae @Bruno Richart voce testou no emulador ou num device real?
porque realmente é estranho, pois na pagina funciona normal, assim, tenta adaptar seu componente webview seguindo esse link https://github.com/examplecode/chromium_android_webview, se tudo pifar, verifique as bibliotecas de media do seu projeto

Comment: Muito Obrigado @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho irei testar, achei estranho também.